# PHP form won't insert into MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

There are many such errors but this one is mine.

I have a PHP ticketing type form that I want to insert information into a MYSQL database.

Here is the PHP form:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="ticket-form" id="ticket-form" action="get_response.php" method="POST">
      <p>Please provide your first name: <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="John" required></p>
      <p>Please provide your last name: <input type="text" name ="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Smith" required></p>
      <p>Please indicate if you are a company or a contractor:
        <input type="radio" name="clientType" id="clientType" value="company">Company
        <input type="radio" name="clientType" id="clientType" value="contractor" checked>Contractor</p>
      <p>Please provide an email address: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="John123@example.com"><br></p>
      <p>Please provide a phone number if you'd prefer: <input type="text" name="number" id="number" max="13" placeholder="07654321234"><br></p>
      <p>Please detail your query, going in to as much detail as possible: </p>
      <textarea name="query" id="query" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Please detail the nature of your issue, going in to as much detail as possible."></textarea><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the get_response.php

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
require_once("index.php");
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datestring = $datetime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstName']);
  $second_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastName']);
  $client_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['clientType']);
  $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['query']);
  $phone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['number']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO
    tickets (first_name, second_name, client_type, email_address, phone_number, query)
    VALUES
    ('$first_name', '$second_name', '$client_type', '$email_address', '$phone_number', '$query')";
    if($conn->query($sql)){
      echo "<p>Thank you for your email!</p>
      <p> We aim to respond to your query as soon as possible.
      Please allow 2 business days for a response and check spam folders.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . mysqli_error($conn) . ']');
      }
  // else
  // {
  //   echo "<p>Please supply valid information.</p>";
  // }
mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

```
php config.php
```

Will indicate a successful connection with the $conn variable, but to eliminate the issue:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "tickets";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} ?>
```

```
php get_response.php
```

Will insert empty data into the database. Yet the form does not work by posting the information.

I know there might be other bugs. I'm very new to PHP and MYSQL. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Some error logs as requested.That's all there is from today.

```
[Fri Nov 01 12:24:51.342604 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 673:tid 140589056359360] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 01 12:24:51.343298 2019] [core:notice] [pid 673:tid 140589056359360] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Edit2 : Solved, sorta.

I tried remaking the form in my regular Mac OS X operating system and it works fine. There seems to have been something fundamentally wrong with either Virtual box, how it communicates with modern OS X software or some personal configuration. Although I can connect to mysql in the Linux command line it won't work through the form.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/). Use [prepared statements](https://bobby-tables.com/php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/) the string is not safe!

Comment: What errors are you getting in the web server log?

Comment: So it is inserting, but inserting empty values? Please turn on error reporting and then report back with the errors - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display and also https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

Comment: Hi, it's not inserting anything from form only from ```php get_response.php``` on command line. which makes me think it's to do with how the form is connected. Roger on the SQL vulnerability, SQL injections still a topic I'm learning about, that will all be rectified before I ever made it live. I'll edit with error logs.

Comment: I think you're mixing the OO style of connecting with the procedural style. Can you please alter config.php's if statement to: `if (!$conn) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}`. See `Procedural Style` section in https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-examples.  Also, turn on error reporting. This will show you where you're going wrong very quickly.

Comment: Hi @waterloomatt, I have done so but the connection isn't the problem. Config works so there is a $conn, it just doesn't post.

Comment: You need to help us out by doing some debugging. Can you please show us the output of `var_dump($_POST)`, `var_dump($first_name)`, and `var_dump($sql)`?

Comment: Hi, again none are updating with manual form submission which makes me think it isn't being executed and is to do with how I've configured it. On executing get_response.php from command line, they update as would be expected.

Comment: OK - so if I understand you correctly, your form isn't even posting to your script. If your form action is `action="get_response.php"` then it is posting to http://localhost/get_response.php, right? Is that the correct path or is that file buried in a sub directory?

Comment: Thanks, yes it is configured to the right path and is all the same level

Answer (score 1):

I had a spare 20mins whilst installing MS SQL Server so quickly refactored your code to make use of `prepared statements` to mitigate SQL injection attacks. It is not tested so there might be minor errors which I overlooked but I hope it'll prove useful

```
<?php

    $status=false;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $errors=array();
        $args=array(
            'firstName'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'lastName'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'clientType'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'email'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'query'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'number'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );

        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field ){
            if( !isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) $errors[]=sprintf( 'The field "%s" is not set', $field );
        }

        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Unknown field "%s"', $field );
        }

        if( empty( $errors ) ){
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );


            require_once 'config.php';
            require_once 'index.php';



            $sql='insert into `tickets` 
                ( `first_name`, `second_name`, `client_type`, `email_address`, `phone_number`, `query` ) 
                values 
                ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt )$errors[]='The SQL Prepared Statement failed';

            $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $firstName, $lastName, $clientType, $email, $query, $number );
            $stmt->execute();

            $status=$conn->affected_rows;

        }
    }
?>
<html lang='en' dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='ticket-form' method='POST'>
            <?php

                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                    if( !empty( $errors ) ){

                        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($errors,true) );

                    } else {

                        if( $status ){

                            echo "
                            <p>Thank you for your email!</p>
                            <p> We aim to respond to your query as soon as possible.
                            Please allow 2 business days for a response and check spam folders.</p>";
                        }
                    }
                }

            ?>
            <label>Please provide your first name: <input type='text' name='firstName' placeholder='John' required></label>
            <label>Please provide your last name: <input type='text' name ='lastName' placeholder='Smith' required></label>

            <label>
                Please indicate if you are a company or a contractor:
                <input type='radio' name='clientType' value='company'>Company
                <input type='radio' name='clientType' value='contractor' checked>Contractor
            </label>

            <label>Please provide an email address: <input type='email' name='email' id='email' placeholder='John123@example.com'></label>
            <label>Please provide a phone number if you'd prefer: <input type='text' name='number' id='number' max='13' placeholder='07654321234'></label>

            <label>
                Please detail your query, going in to as much detail as possible:
                <textarea name='query' rows='8' cols='80' placeholder='Please detail the nature of your issue, going in to as much detail as possible.'></textarea>
            </label>

            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciated. Please note, my solicited issue remains unresolved.

Comment: The form itself POSTs fine so I think your issue lies elsewhere

Comment: Hi, quite possibly, but connection is fine and only form doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: at the top of `get_response.php` put `exit( print_r( $_POST,1) );` or similar to begin debugging. Enable error reporting too

Comment: one thing you might need to check is that the required files are actually being included correctly. - `var_dump( get_included_files() );`